# dataGridView1_CellContentClick event not fire in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In my windows form application I have added `DataGridViewLinkColumn` for `delete` record of a particular row, whenever I click on `Delete` linklabel and for doing this I have added `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` event like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace search
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Musewerx\\My Documents\\Contacts.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void bindDatagridview()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from contactsinfo", connection);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            clear();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
          string contactname = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ContactName"].Value.ToString();
            string contactnumber = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ContactNumber"].Value.ToString();

            if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from contactsinfo where ContactName = '" + contactname.ToString() + "', and ContactNumber ='" + contactnumber.ToString() + "'", connection);
                connection.Open();
                da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

        }

        public void clear()
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact Name");
            }
            else if(textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact Number");
            }
            else
            {
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into contactsinfo(ContactName,ContactNumber) Values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')", connection);
            connection.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            bindDatagridview();
            clear();
            connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindDatagridview();

            DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            dgvLink.HeaderText = "Delete";
            dgvLink.Name = "lnk_delete";
            dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
            dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
            dgvLink.Text = "Delete";

            bool check = dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("lnk_delete");
            if (check == false)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I click on the `Delete` linklabel, its not going into the `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` event.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the CellContentClicked with CellMouseClick event.

CellContentClicked fires up when you click on the Content of cell and if the cell has some empty speces and you click on that it won't fire up. but CellMouseClick will fire up when you click in every where of cell.